# How can I have multiply a pixel width value with LESS Css?

Tags: css, less

I am trying to set up padding on some \ elements styled as pills, and I want to dynamically change the padding. I know I can do:

```
@pill-padding-v: 8px;
@pill-padding-h: 15px;

padding:@pill-padding-v @pill-padding-h;
```

that renders this - and seems to work fine:

```
padding:8px 15px;
```

But how can I have LESS add 1px of padding to that?

```
@pill-padding-v: 8;
@pill-padding-h: 15;

@pill-padding-v: (@pill-padding-v + 1)
@pill-padding-h: (@pill-padding-h + 1)

padding:@pill-padding-vpx @pill-padding-hpx;
```

The main probelem seems to be adding "px" as part of the variable name I'm getting a compile error. Also I think it is syntactically incorrect to use `8 px` instead of `8px` and that seems to break in browsers, too.

How can I have multiply a pixel width value with LESS Css?

Comment: "Multiply" or "add"? You seem to be confused (or maybe it's just me).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're right that adding the `px` to the variable is causing problems. I actually tried the interpolation syntax and it didn't help, but you should be specifying units anyways in your variables (`px`, `em`, `%`...), like in your first working example.

You said "multiply" but I think you meant "add". There shouldn't be any problem, try this:

```
@pill-padding-v: 8px;
@pill-padding-h: 15px;

@pill-padding-v: (@pill-padding-v + 1);
@pill-padding-h: (@pill-padding-h + 1);

element {
    padding:@pill-padding-v @pill-padding-h;
}
```

Output should be:

```
element { padding:9px 16px; }
```

...although, you might want to just use another variable name or add the 1px right in the style declaration. I don't think re-declaring variables is good practice, and was actually surprised it worked.

Comment: Nice. Logically it just didn't seem like LESS's javascript style syntax could take (8px + 1) and get 9px.

Comment: I'm not sure why this should be the case but the parentheses around the equation are absolutely required - does "+" have some meaning in CSS (aside from "immediate sibling" when used in a selector)?

Comment: @Jonz As far as I know `+` is not used in CSS for any other purpose. I'm using a PHP port of LESS and it's pretty "smart" about operators, I usually don't use the parens.

Comment: @Jonz `+` can be used in the selector portion of a CSS declaration to select the next sibling. E.g. `.whatever + p` to select the `p` next to (after) `.whatever` -- but I doubt this is related...

Answer (score 8):

Aside from add, you can perform any mathematical calculation using LESS this way:

```
@pill-padding-v: 8;
@pill-padding-h: 15;

element {
/* the numbers I'm multiplying by are arbitrary,
but the value defined in the LESS variable will append
the unit that you multiply it by. */
padding: calc(@pill-padding-v * 3px) calc(@pill-padding-h * 2px);
}
```

LESS outputs:

```
element {
   padding:calc(24px) calc(30px);
}
```

Even though it's wrapped in the calc function, it's fine, because the result of the "equation" with no math operator, is that value anyway.

**User seven-phases-max offers a good point:** you don't need the `calc()` function in the LESS.  It can be written in LESS as:

```
element {
   padding: (@pill-padding-v * 3px) (@pill-padding-h * 2px);
}
```

Comment: And of is the purpose of the `calc` there?

Comment: The calc() function will do some math to figure out a value for you.  And the magic is when you multiply it by a number with a unit (em, px, etc), the result takes on that unit.

Comment: Yes, sorry for non-clear question. I know what `calc` means in CSS, but what is it doing in `calc(24px)`? Hint: you *don't* need `calc` for `@pill-padding-v * 3px` etc.

Comment: It's doing absolutely nothing in `calc(24px)`.  That's the output of LESS.  The point is that LESS did the math, but you can't strip out the word "calc" from the resulting CSS. It doesn't matter, however, because it's like saying "calculate the number 5" and the result is of course 5.

Comment: To strip `calc` from the resulting CSS just strip it from the Less code, e.g. the code in your answer could be just: `padding: (@pill-padding-v * 3px) (@pill-padding-h * 2px);`.